# Servlet 3, <async-supported>true</async-supported> in web.xml vs asyncSupported=false

Tags: java, servlets, asynchronous, servlet-3.0

In my application

`web.xml` contains

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>PurchaseServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.codecypher.PurchaseServlet</servlet-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
```

And in main `servlet class`

```
@WebServlet(name="PurchaseServlet", urlPatterns={"/PurchaseServlet"},asyncSupported=false)
```

I am not able to identify type of servlet after deployment, whether is it Sync/Async?

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. Why are you using xml AND annotations to define your servlet. Pick one or the other.

Comment: @JBNizet I understand your question, my problem is we have web.xml which we are not allowed to change and now I have to test some quick tests.

Comment: But that doesn't explain what you're asking. What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

If async requests are enabled for a Servlet, then [ServletRequest.isAsyncSupported()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#isAsyncSupported%28%29) will return true for requests sent to this Servlet.

If you configure a servlet via annotation and via `web.xml` using the same servlet name then the `web.xml`will override annotation values.

Comment: you are correct, but what is actual priority web.xml or Class definition?

Comment: @ChiragVisavadia explained the priority. By the way you should edit your post since you set `async=true` in both cases.